# Codeception: What combinations of test groups are possible?

Tags: php, testing, codeception

Codeception allows to assign tests to one or multiple groups (see https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage.html#groups). These groups may be included or excluded when a testsuite is started (see https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Commands.html#Run) using `--group [Groups of tests to be executed (multiple values allowed)]` and/or `--skip-group [Skip selected groups (multiple values allowed)]`.

In what way are tests of multiple given groups combined? `AND` or `OR`? And what happens with test which don't have any group, are they executed anyways?

How do `group` and `skip-group` interact with each other? Has one precedence over the other?

The documentation tells nothing about these combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I tested all combinations in Codeception 2.5 and came to the following conclusion (`--group` = `-g`, `--skip-group` = `-x`).

Run all tests, with and without groups assigned

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Run only tests having the group »admin« *or* »database« assigned

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run -g admin -g database
```

Run all tests, including tests without any group, except those having the
group »form« assigned

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run -x form
```

Run only tests having the group »admin« assigned, except those having the
group »form« assigned as well

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run -g admin -x form
```